# How do I swap two layers in altium?

Tags: pcb-design, altium

I have two inner layers in altium for a flex cable, I want to swap one copper layer with the other without having to delete or copy everything. Is there a way to swap two PCB layers while maintaining everything on that layer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy way is to just tell the board shop what order you want, or to imply the required order by renaming the Gerber files to indicate the desired order.

I provide a readme.txt file with a board order containing the following (among other information):

```
The following files are required for this job:
  alarm-Front.GTL   Component side copper photoplot file
  alarm-Back.GBL   Solder side copper photoplot file
  alarm-SilkS-Front.GTO   Component layout silkscreen
  alarm-MASK-Front.GBS   Solder Mask
  alarm.drl   Drill file
  readme.txt    This file
```

Answer (score 3):

If they are not top or bottom layer you can use the Design->Layer Stack Manager to move the layers around (and you can rename them to make sense).

Answer (score 0):

Simply select the layer which you want to change. And then select any track or plane on that layer then press tab which automatically selects all of the tracks/vias/polygons/components and open properties panel there you have an option for layer selection simply just change the layer and vice versa for the other layer. This is how you swap the layer. Thanks